# BroadcastReceiver in Android is not working with Calendars from a month

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Broadcast Receiver in Android is not working with Calendars from a month. It was working fine on all versions of android before.

```
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />
    <data android:host="com.android.calendar" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

I have used the above code in Manifest file. My receiver was working fine with the above code in manifest file but when I come back today and see it's not working on the same device on which it was working fine. This was working fine in December but now it's not working. May I know if Google has changed something?

Comment: same for me. Did you ever solve it?